# Add a id/class to the <tr> generated by the asp.net DataList control

Tags: .net, asp.net, datalist

My question is dealing with the DataList control. I am trying to add a click event to the rows of the "table" in the OnItemDataBound event.

The problem I'm having is I can't get a reference (through a row id attribute) to the "row" being generated by the DataList control (and more specifically the item template).  **Is there a way to add id attributes to the rows being generated by the item template?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create your own [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemtemplate.aspx) for it.